# Flair not working correctly

Tags: bug, status-norepro

See my [profile](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/31683/imazik).

[image]

and the [flair](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/31683/imazik/flair) of my account
[image]

Why it appears like this?

It shows the profile picture of another beta account.

I have changed the profile picture again to solve this, but same result.

Comment: Can you possible post a screen shot of what you're seeing? I only know what I'm seeing and I don't know if that's what you intended me to see or not.

Comment: They're getting at the fact that the network profile / combined network flair is using the Xcode icon, where all of the accounts have been updated to use a more specific icon like the green droplet as seen here. I've never used a different icon so I'm unsure of what the problem could be. Add to it that the account listings at stackexchange.com aren't actually an account type that you manipulate as you would on an actual SE site...

Comment: @IanC., added screenshot, now find the issue, thnx

Comment: On my end, I see *your* picture when I view your flair page: http://imgur.com/szRw0vr. It appears the flair page, when *you* view it, is taking the image you have associated with your sports SE account: http://sports.stackexchange.com/users/753/sports-fan -- try changing all your accounts to use the same image.

Comment: From the Flair page: "please note that only sites where you have more than 200 reputation will appear, and that flair is only updated once every 24-36 hours"

Answer (score 1):

Status aside, I don't doubt that you saw this, but I don't see it, and I doubt you see it anymore either. Remember, these images are cached - as patrix notes, you won't see changes to your profile reflected for a while.